# DatePicker setting month wrong

Tags: java, sql, datepicker

Can anyone tell me why the date is being set to next month instead of this month?

Even though im setting the dateFormatted variable as "28/08/2014" its setting the date to "28/07/2014".

I can simply go -1 at the month but it will mess up the date in January.

Is there some other way i should be setting the date?

Thanks

```
        UtilDateModel model;
        JDatePanelImpl datePanel;
        DatePickerImpl datePicker;

        model = new UtilDateModel();
        model.setDate(yearInt, monthInt, dayInt);
        model.setSelected(true);
        datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
        datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel);


        // String dateFormatted = (String) result[1];
        String dateFormatted = "28/08/2014";
        System.out.println("Date Formatted : " + (String) result[1]);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(dateFormatted.substring(0, 2)); // Correct
        int month = Integer.parseInt(dateFormatted.substring(3, 5)); // Correct
        int year = Integer.parseInt(dateFormatted.substring(6, 10)); // Correct
        System.out.println(day);
        System.out.println(month);
        System.out.println(year);
        model.setDate(year, month, day);
        model.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing date parsing wrong, please use a SimpleDateFormat or the like

The problem that you are seeing is probably related to the fact that some fields are 0-based and some are 1-based.

**UPDATE**

Dates should not be stored as strings in the database, instead use the available date types.

Date parsing in general is much trickier than you might think. DST, leap years, language,... all comes into play.

The newest java iteration has a complete rewrite for date handling based on joda time (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) but you can also use the "old" way of date parsing in java which is not bad, simply different.

You should look at the javadoc of SimpleDateFormat, it will tell you why you need lower case "yyyy" for example and upper case "MM". The formatter will give you a Date which you can probe with Calendar for the required fields.

All the while it will take into account all the niggling details about date handling.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense with the 0 index array. Also when you say im Parsing it wrong could you give me a quick explanation or link of how to set a DatePicker from a String. For example its stored in database as String "28/08/2014". Is this wrong way to store date in SQL? Also we use a different format in Ireland. It hink thats why i couldnt use SimpleDateFormat. We use DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not known with the 'JDatePicker' package, but after doing some research, i've found [this](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/how-to-use-jdatepicker-to-display-calendar-component), please read article 3 on this page. It says month number is 0 based, so januari should be 0 ( 1st month minus 1).